# Facebook Web App does not ask which page to manage

Tags: php, symfony, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a Facebook Web App using PHP SDK in Symfony. It's working correctly. It asks for permissions and then posts the user's posts on our system to their Facebook Page. Now clients want that if a user manages multiple pages, it should ask for which page they want to give access to. The App selects the first page the user manages as default and gets the access token for it.

My question is how is it possible so that the App returns the Pages list and ask user for which page they want to give access to our App?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of all managed Pages including their Page Tokens with the `/me/accounts` endpoint:

```
/me/accounts?fields=name,access_token
```

You can´t just authorize one single Page, you can only authorize the neccessary permissions (`manage_pages`, `publish_pages`).

Comment: Thank you @luschn for your answer. I am using this url to get Page Access token but this happens after the control returns to my application. I want the Facebook Dialog when it asks for permission to show the pages and give the user the choice to choose which Page he wants me to get access to. Then I will get that Page access token.

Comment: you can´t just authorize one single page, you can only authorize the neccessary permissions (manage_pages, publish_pages). added that info to my answer.

Comment: Thank you again. Then how would I know on which page I should publish the Post or Press Release the User has created in my system? Because I will have access to all of his/her pages then I can push to a wrong Page.

Comment: present a list of his pages to the user then.

Comment: I will have to discuss this with my CEO but I am marking your answer as accepted. Thank you for your time.